# Trouble converting double to string

Tags: java, string, constructor, double, syntax-error

I am making a program that asks 5 students to input their name and gpa, which will calculate the lowest and highest gpa, as well as the average. I keep on getting the "incompatible type" error, even though i have already initialized the variables in the constructor.

```
System.out.println("Please enter the gpa for the second student");
gpa2 = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Please enter the name for the third student");
student3 = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter the gpa for the third student");
gpa3 = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Please enter the name for the fourth student");
student4 = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter the gpa for the fourth student");
gpa4 = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Please enter the name for the last student");
student5 = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter the gpa for the last student");
gpa5 = scan.nextDouble();
//use scanner to get the gpa



System.out.println("Student Name /" + " Student GPA");
System.out.println("----------------------------);
System.out.println(student1 +"   /       "+ gpa1);
System.out.println(student2 +"   /       "+ gpa2);
System.out.println(student3 +"   /       "+ gpa3);
System.out.println(student4 +"   /       "+ gpa4);
System.out.println(student5 +"   /       "+ gpa5);

/**
 * Creates objScore object and passas in student parameters to class StudentScore...name and GPA scores
 */
StudentScore objScore = new StudentScore(student1, gpa1, student2, gpa2, student3, gpa3, student4, gpa4, student5, gpa5);
```

> 1 error found:
>
> **File:** C:\Users\Mikey Espinal\OneDrive\Documents\StudentScoreTester.java   [line: 46]
>
> **Error:** incompatible types: double cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Comment: I am gonna guess on the code you didn't share and suggest that there is an error on line 4?

Comment: What does your StudentScore constructor look like ?

Comment: Please supply source code directly in the post using '{}' button or surrounding in like this \`source code\`

Comment: You need to put your code in the post if you want any help.

Comment: I've edited the actual text into the post and removed the screenshot. Feel free to correct any mistranscriptions

Comment: Per your title, you're having trouble converting double to a string, because no where in your code do you attempt to do so. You need to make an explicit conversion prior to / within your constructor call.

Comment: @zposten the error is thrown on OP's constructor call to `StudentScore`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `String.valueOf(gpa1)` instead of `gpa1`. That converts your `double` to `String`. The same need to do with the other `double`s (`gpa2`, `gpa3`, ...).

Comment: Personally I think using `String.valueOf()` is silly when it does nothing aside from directly call `Double.toString()`.

Comment: Also, Java will automatically convert the gpa's in the print statements to strings because they're being concatenated to a string.  I don't believe that is his issue.

Comment: @zposten the print statements have nothing to do with the constructor call.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is your code does not call scan.nextLine() after each scan.nextDouble().

Answer (score 2):

Your code has no issue. Please check the constructor of StudentScore class. I am damn sure you have used String everywhere instead of double for all gpa values. Sol 1: Either convert gpa to String explicitly as suggested above by Andrew String.valueOf(gpa1) and then pass to constructor or 
Sol2: Change your constructor and use Double/double at all gpa places.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess that you declared the `gpaX` variables as of type `String`. Declare them of type `double` instead - that way, you will store them as a `double` until they are converted to strings for the purpose of printing.

Answer (score 2):

you are concatenating a string with a double value when printing the lines which is not compatible in java.
All you need to do is convert the type double to String.This can be done using **String.valueOf()** function.
Try:
System.out.println(student1 +"   /       "+ String.valueOf(gpa1);